# Convert array to nodes

Tags: c++, arrays, graph, artificial-intelligence, nodes

Let me start off with saying that I have very basic knowledge of nodes and graphs.

My goal is to make a solver for a maze which is stored as an array. I know exactly how to implement the algorithm for solving (I'm actually implementing a couple of them) but what my problem is, is that I am very confused on how to implement the nodes that the solver will use in each empty cell.

Here is an example array:

```
char maze[5][9] = 
        "#########",
        "#  #    #",
        "# ## ## #",
        "#     # #",
        "#########"
```

My solver starts at the top left and the solution (exit) is at the bottom right.

I've read up on how nodes work and how graphs are implemented, so here is how I *think* I need to make this:

- Starting point will become a node
- Each node will have as property the column and the row number
- Each node will also have as property the visited state
- Visited state can be `visited`, `visited and leads to dead end`, `not visited`
- Every time a node gets visited, every directly adjacent, empty and not visited cell becomes the visited node's child
- Every visited node gets put on top of the solutionPath stack (and marked on the map as '*')
- Every node that led to a dead end is removed from the stack (and marked on the map as '~')

Example of finished maze:

```
"#########",
"#*~#****#",
"#*##*##*#",
"#****~#*#",
"#########"
```

Basically my question is, am I doing something really stupid here with my way of thinking (since I am really inexperienced with nodes) and if it is could you please explain to me why? Also if possible provide me other websites to check which implement examples of graphs on real world applications so I can get a better grasp of it.

Comment: Each open (ie. not-a-wall) position in your maze is a node.  Each node should have edges to its neighbors.  Once you've converted the 2-D array representation to a general graph structure, you should be able to implement whatever graph traversal algorithms you wish on it.  There are ways you can optimize this (using weighted graphs for example), but that should get you started.

Comment: I am not looking into doing a preprocess on the whole maze because in that way I will visit every cell even if I don't have to. I am looking into making the nodes as I go.

Comment: I guess it's not _necessary_ to preprocess, but depending on what algorithm you're using to traverse the maze, it may want to know how many nodes there are _a priori_.  For example, most formulations of Djisktra's algorithm assume you have the set of nodes and edges at the beginning.  Your graph is actually implicitly represented in the grid form, with nodes at each open point, and edges between neighboring open points.  You should be able to implement any graph algorithm you want on this representation if you understand that mapping and build it into the code.

Comment: FWIW, a long time ago I wrote a BFS implementation that worked directly on the grid representation.  It didn't even talk in terms of nodes and edges, but that's effectively what it was doing.  You can find it here:  http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/mso_contest/contest_9/  The node-edge relationship was baked into the code:  When visiting a cell in the maze, it "knew" that cell was connected to its spatial neighbors.  There are no explicit edges, only implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends on what you find most important in the problem. If you're searching for **efficiency** and **speed** - you're adding way too many nodes. There's no need for so many.

### The efficient method

Your solver only needs nodes at the start and end of the path, and at every possible corner on the map. Like this:

```
"#########",
"#oo#o  o#",
"# ## ## #",
"#o  oo#o#",
"#########"
```

There's no real need to test the other places on the map - you'll either HAVE TO walk thru them, or won't have need to even bother testing.

If it helps you - I got a template `digraph` class that I designed for simple graph representation. It's not very well written, but it's perfect for showing the possible solution.

```
#include <set>
#include <map>

template <class _nodeType, class _edgeType>
class digraph
{
public:
    set<_nodeType> _nodes;
    map<pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>,_edgeType> _edges;
};
```

I use this class to find a path in a tower defence game using the **Dijkstra's** algorithm. The representation should be sufficient for any other algorithm tho.

Nodes can be of any given type - you'll probably end up using `pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>`. The `_edges` connect two `_nodes` by their `position` in the set.

### The easy to code method

On the other hand - if you're looking for an **easy to implement** method - you just need to treat every free space in the array as a possible node. And if that's what you're looking for - there's no need for designing a graph, because the array represents the problem in a perfect way.

You don't need dedicated classes to solve it this way.

```
bool myMap[9][5]; //the array containing the map info. 0 = impassable, 1 = passable
vector<pair<int,int>> route; //the way you need to go
pair<int,int> start = pair<int,int>(1,1); //The route starts at (1,1)
pair<int,int> end = pair<int,int>(7,3); //The road ends at (7,3)

route = findWay(myMap,start,end); //Finding the way with the algorithm you code
```

Where `findWay` has a prototype of `vector<pair<int,int>> findWay(int[][] map, pair<int,int> begin, pair<int,int> end)`, and implements the algorithm you desire. Inside the function you'll probably need another two dimensional array of type bool, that indicates which places were tested.

When the algorithm finds a route, you usually have to read it in reverse, but I guess it depends on the algorithm.

In your particular example, myMap would contain:

```
bool myMap[9][5] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,
                    0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,
                    0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

And `findWay` would return a `vector` containing `(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(4,2),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(7,2),(7,3)`

Comment: Yes optimization is not my goal here I am just looking to find the easiest way to implement a DFS, after that a BFS and later Dijkstra so I can get accustomed with those 3 algorithm and more so with the nodes. So if I get this right in order to use nodes I first need to make a node class which will contain all my properties and such? Can't I just create a simple struct? But my main problem is how do I represent a node having multiple children which I have to add each one of them to the stack.

Comment: @Powerbyte - the class I gave you represents a whole graph. You don't need a `node` class, but it would actually help you in implementation I guess. If you don't understand my code, read a bit about [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/). I'll update the answer in a moment, check it out if you wish.

Comment: thank you for the reply I found another way to do it in the end without a graph but your way will certainly help me in the future as reference